# Update table for only one record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question, I want to edit customer information, but I only want to update record of one customer at a time. I tried to add where _SESSION['customerCode'] but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
$connection = 
mysql_connect("com-db-02.student-cit.local", "team16", "DbSLzU")
or die (mysql_error());


$db = mysql_select_db("team16") or die(mysql_error());

$FName = $_POST['fname'];
$LName = $_POST['lname'];
$Email = $_POST['custemail'];
$Address = $_POST['address'];
$Town = $_POST['town'];
$County = $_POST['county'];
$Eircode = $_POST['eircode'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];


$query = mysql_query("UPDATE CUSTOMER set custFName = '$FName', custLName = '$LName', custemail = '$Email' where customerCode = "$_SESSION['customerCode']"") or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

I get an error  unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE)

Also is it possible to add not update those fields that are blank, so if customer wants to change their address only, other fields won't get wiped out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake on your concatination. Make it like this `.$_SESSION['customerCode']`

Try the code below.

```
session_start();
$custCode = $_SESSION['customerCode'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE CUSTOMER set custFName = '$FName', custLName = '$LName', custemail = '$Email' where customerCode = ".$custCode) or die(mysql_error())
```

> Also is it possible to add not update those fields that are blank, so
>   if customer wants to change their address only, other fields won't get
>   wiped out

This was already been answered here before. Search for **MySQL `COALESCE`**

You can check the following:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36748

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525287/4672534

Comment: What version of PHP you have? BTW, try to assign the session data first to a variable. `$custCode = $_SESSION['customerCode'];` then `where customerCode = ".$custCode`

Comment: also don't forget to put a session_start(); before using the $_SESSION.

Comment: I don't know why, but I was missing session_start(); from the code, works now :)